# Why when I tried to execute following test code, I got "The first character of a path should be `/` or `*`" error?

Tags: jestjs, fastify

When I tried to execute following test code, I got error like "The first character of a path should be `/` or `*`"

**archives.test.ts**

```
import ...

describe('Get All Archived', () => {
test('it must return ok', async () => {


        const app = init()

        const response = await app.inject().get('/client/archives')


        const body = JSON.parse(response.body)

        expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200)
        expect(body.status).toBe('ok')
        expect(body.data.length).toBe(0)
    })
})
```

My code:

**api.ts**

```
import fastify, { FastifyInstance } from 'fastify'
other imports...

export const init = (): FastifyInstance => {
    const app = fastify()

    app.addContentTypeParser('application/json', { parseAs: 'string' }, parseApplicationJson)

    app.register(ArchivesPlugin)

    return app
}

const proxy = awsLambdaFastify(init())
export const handler = proxy
```

**ArchivesPlugin.ts**

```
import fp from 'fastify-plugin'
import { FastifyInstance, FastifyPluginAsync } from 'fastify'

import { register } from '../controllers/archives'

const ArchivesPlugin: FastifyPluginAsync = async (app: FastifyInstance) => {
    await register(app)
}

export default fp(ArchivesPlugin)
```

**register.ts**

```
import { FastifyInstance, FastifyRequest } from 'fastify'
other imports...

const handlers = {

    code content
    },
}

export async function register(app: FastifyInstance) {
    app.route({
        method: 'GET',
        url: `${prefix}/archives`,
        schema: { ...GetArchiveListResponse, tags: ['archives'] },
        handler: handlers.index,
    })
}
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you tried `app.inject('/client/archives')`?

Comment: Yes. I tried as follows too; const response = await app.inject({
            method:'GET',
            url: `/client/archives`,
        })

Comment: Does the app start normally? I think there could be some `prefix` misuse. Do you use `fastify-autoload`? Unfortunately, the code above is not enough to suggest the right solution at first sight

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. Error caused by the prefix. When called register.ts, prefix seemed undefined. That's why I was getting the error. After I'd changed, it was solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by ${prefix} in register.ts which is given above. When called register.ts, prefix seemed undefined. That's why I was getting the error.